Calculating maximum of a function of several variables using a computer
Consider the function
$$f(r,s,t,a,b)=rst-e^{t^a}-e^{r^b}-s(\ln(s))^{\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}}$$
where $r$, $t>0$ and $a$, $b$, $s\geq1.$
Is there any software that can calculate approximately the maximum point of this function with small error if there exist one?
I need to study this function to understand one inequality that is used in a article that I'm studying. For more reference, I'm trying to convince myself that the inequality in this post is true
How to understand the last step of the proof of this inequality?.
Thank you for the attention and every help will be appreciated!

You can try optimization methods like Hooke-Jeeves, Nelder-Mead, steepest descent and so on.

@PierreCarre Thank you, do you recommend any software that can use these methods ?

For instance, Wolfram Mathematica has a module named "FindMaximum" that implements such methods (also including constrained optimization). If you lookup scipy it will also do the trick.
